# Web Platform Installer - Wants to instal SQL 2008 Express when I already have SQL 2008 Standard installed

Tags: sql-server, web-platform-installer

I'm finding my use of the Web Platform Installer somewhat muted by it's insistence on trying to install SQL Express when I already have a full copy of SQL Server installed.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to get WPI to recognise that I have SQL Server installed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it looks like WPI just treats express as part of the package.  If you don't have any data in SQL Standard yet you could uninstall it, install WPI, and upgrade the edition after it's in place.

Comment: I invariably do have data in the full versions; instead, I either suck it up and let WPI install Express, or I install whatever packages I need manually...